# How do audiobook players manage to quickly speedup/slowdown playback speed without using more memory?

Tags: audio, algorithms, real-time, time-domain, sola

Many audiobook player apps on Android have a reading speed slider which lets us choose the reading speed e.g. `0.5x 0.75x 1.00x 1.25x 1.50x`. This is time-stretching without pitch shifting.

I have some idea about how this could be done using `PSOLA` algorithm(s), but they would need extra memory equivalent to the memory of original audio file.

ex.

```
Original audio file -> PSOLA -> Modified audio file
```

But these Andorid apps don't seem to use double the memory when we try to change reading speed. How do they do an `in place` time stretching/shortening so quickly?

---

edit. I found this [YouTube engineering blog](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2017/09/variable-speed-playback-on-mobile.html), which led me to [`sonic`](https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic/blob/master/doc/index.md) library, which in turn led me to a description of [`PICOLA` algorithm](https://web.archive.org/web/20120731100136/http://keizai.yokkaichi-u.ac.jp/~ikeda/research/picola.html).

I don't understand the algorithm from the images though. Could anyone please explain? What do those triangles mean? How do they decide these `A` and `B` points?

**Time scale expansion procedure of the PICOLA** 
[image]

Comment: I can try write about picola, but for while you can read about TDHS [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27437/what-is-the-difference-between-psola-and-tdhs-time-scaling-or-pitch-shifting)

Comment: @ederwander could you please post your answer. will be much appreciated

Comment: I finally had time to write about it

Answer (score 1):

WOW long gap to answer this question, maybe if I have a Einstein brain I can understand the image, what is not my case lol.

I haved touched in this algorithm in a long time ago, and I remember that was a surprised for me that almost no one around the Web talks about the Algorithm from Morita Naotaka, I tryed seach his original paper but I cant found online, I think that it is in Japanese, well I dont know ...

So I learned about it looking at among number of patents that make references to the Morita Naotaka, and I freeze when I see a lot of patents around 2000 years that use the same code.

As far as I know this algorithm was derived from `TDHS`, has advantages about TDHS, this does the job using just Period size Buffer. And believe me it's as easy to code as TDHS.

So lets go, take a look at the Yamaha Patent number `US8085953` this is basicly the `PICOLA` from Morita Naotaka...

Here one image from this Patent that is infinity better to understand how this works to compress :

[image]

Looks like one TDHS using a triangular window, but take a look how it are cutting `wave A` and `wave B` in the exact Period size(`Lp`), then they are crossfaded `A + B`. this image seems to be an compression using rate = `0.6` factor(alpha),  `L` can be determined using:

$$ \begin{align}
L & = \operatorname{round}\left(\frac{L_p}{\alpha-1}\right) 
\end{align} $$

And here how its works to expansion:

[image]

Now `L` can be determined using:

$$ \begin{align}
L & = \operatorname{round}\left(L_p\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right) 
\end{align} $$

Time ago I show a basic code to compress based in `TDHS` [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/27463/1081), now lets try a litle bit more complex and complete example to expand (it will slowdown), so based in this images/equations, here my `PICOLA` Algorithm:

```
alpha=0.5;

f=735;
Fs=44100;
signal= 0.9*sin(2*pi*f/Fs*(1:44100)); signal = signal';

period= 60; % is it (Fs/F)

[signal,Fs]=audioread('ederwander.wav');
   
nsamples = length(signal);
out=zeros(1,floor(nsamples/alpha));
inptr=1;
outptr=1;


minF = 50;
maxF = 900;
     
minP = floor(Fs/maxF);
maxP = floor(Fs/minF);


winsize = 1024;

while ( inptr+winsize <= nsamples )

    
    %chunk used to find the period, its need be >= MaxP
    windowedSignal=signal(inptr:inptr+winsize);

    %Basic Autocorrelation to find the period
    Maximum=-Inf(1);
    for P =minP:maxP
        ac = sum(windowedSignal(1:(winsize)-P) .* windowedSignal(P:(winsize -1)));
        if ac > Maximum
            period=P;
            Maximum=ac;
        end
    end

    period = period-1;

    %split all how shown in the patent picture 
    waveA = signal(inptr:inptr+period-1);
    waveB = signal(inptr+period:(inptr+period*2-1));
    CrossfadeAB = (waveA .* linspace(0,1,period)') + (waveB .* (1-linspace(0,1,period))');
    L = round(period*alpha/(1-alpha));
    waveB_T0 = signal(inptr+period:inptr+L);
    out(outptr:outptr+period-1)=waveA;
    out(outptr+period:outptr+period*2-1)=CrossfadeAB';
    out(outptr+period*2:outptr+period+L)=waveB_T0';

    %increment input and output pointers
    inptr = inptr + L;
    outptr = outptr + L + period;
    

end


%not best choice, just append the end to match the out size, this will click, maybe need crossfade here
if outptr < nsamples/alpha

    fim=floor(nsamples/alpha)-outptr;
    out(outptr:floor(nsamples/alpha))=signal(nsamples-fim:nsamples);

end

plot(out);
sound(out,Fs);
```

I think that standard algorithm of PICOLA just get nice results to `0.5<=alpha<=2`

And one more time it's can be considered a proof of concept to show how its can be done!